# Как сравнить строки в файле excel между собой при помощи python openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Задача такая, каждая строка в таблице excel это анкета с ответами, столбцы соответственно это вопросы анкеты. Требуется в большом количестве анкет (строк) искать одинаковые, вручную делать невозможно, так как очень много анкет. Можно ли каким то образом сравнивать сразу строки полностью? Я новичок в программировании на python, буду рад любой информации.

Comment: Разместите несколько строк разных файлов с ответами, которые вы хотите сравнить и ваш код с попыткой решить задачу.

Comment: "Можно ли каким то образом сравнивать сразу строки полностью?" — можно. `pip install openpyxl` и вперед!